# How to deploy all farm solutions in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Please tell me how to write a Powershell script that will deploy all added farm solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to use a script that will add the solutions to the SharePoint farm, and deploy them by selecting web application you want to install the script.

Follow those links:

- http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Automated-Farm-level-4bc150ce
- http://blog.concurrency.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-2010-deploy-scripts-with-powershell/

Comment: Thank you. Solutions have already been added.
I just can not get to the Administration Center (do not ask why) and I want to deploy all the solutions have already been added.

Answer (score 2):

finally i made the following script which will redeploy all the 200 info-path forms in share-point 2010 which was stucked on deploying because of stopped Timer Service

```
Remove-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue

$forms=Get-SPSolution | ? {($_.Name -like "form-*") -and ($_.Deployed -eq $false)}

foreach($Solution in $forms)    {
    if(($Solution -ne $null) -and ($Solution.ContainsWebApplicationResource){
        Install-SPSolution -identity $Solution.SolutionId  -AllwebApplications -GACDeployment -Force -Confirm:$false
    }
    else    {
        Install-SPSolution -identity $Solution.SolutionId   -GACDeployment -Force -Confirm:$false
    }
}
```

you may need to cancel all stuck in **deploying** jobs (or installing in infoPath Form management  area) with below similar scipt

```
 Get-SPTimerJob | ? {$_.Name -like "Solution-Deployment*" } | % { $_.Delete() }
```

Comment: Unfortunately ,  this script does not resolved my problem .at first it seems to be working but i cannot understand well why no InfoPath Forms deployed Globally in this way and I finally had to Deploy the 200 forms manually , because i was in a hurry. but because the script is working and have some good tips and will not delete it until i found a fix for it